# Displaying a bitmap to full size in imageview

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview, android-imageview, android-bitmap

I am trying to display a bitmap loaded from external card to an imageview that occupies the entire screen. My goal is to display how it is displayed in Gallery app. I tried using `scaletype="center"`, `scaletype="fitXY"` with and without `adjustViewBounds="true"` in the layout xml.

My xml is like this

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="false"
    android:scaleType="center"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/player_imageview" />
```

For example,
This is how my Gallery app displays it
[image: This is how my Gallery app displays it]

This is how my app displays it
[image: This is how my app displays it]

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: have you tried match_parent?

Comment: Yes, I have. If I add "match_parent", the imageview would occupy the entire screen. I don't want that. I want it to occupy only the size of the source bitmap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured answer to the question myself. I browsed through android source code of Gallery app. [Link to the layout of Gallery app](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Gallery/+/android-5.1.1_r38/res/layout/viewimage.xml). They had embedded their custom imageview inside AbsoluteLayout. As AbsoluteLayout is deprecated, I embedded my Imageview inside a FrameLayout.

The solution is

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/player_imageview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#FF000000" />
</FrameLayout>
```

This FrameLayout is placed inside a RelativeLayout. Thus, fixed. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="false"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/player_imageview" />
```

Comment: Thanks. But that didn't work either. I got the same result. :(

Comment: ow I see. please change this line `android:scaleType="fitCenter"` to this: `android:scaleType="centerCrop"`